# Which is the best method to integrate Orbeon Forms with eXist-db?

Tags: orbeon, exist-db

Using Orbeon 2017.2, I have created some forms which save to specific collections in the eXist db.

I then attempted to connect the exist-db Dashboard app to the embedded eXist db within Orbeon to try to access the forms and data with XQuery.  Unfortunately, this resulted in a currupt collection for the Orbeon application data. The error reported was a eXist-db version mismatch (Dashboard was 13, Orbeon was 10).
Is there a way to fix this scenario - removing .lck files from ./exist-data has not worked.

In addition, would it be more advisable to integrate Orbeon forms to an external eXist-db which has the bespoke application installed as a package?

Thanks,
Jake.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as you suspected, if you're planning to use eXist in production, you're better off setting up Orbeon Forms to use an external eXist. Quoting from the documentation:

> The version of eXist which ships with Orbeon Forms is intended for
>   demo purposes only. If you plan to use eXist, we recommend setting up
>   an external eXist database.

And for more information on how to setup an external eXist with Orbeon Forms, see the section on [Removing the built-in eXist database](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/creating-a-production-war#removing-the-built-in-exist-database).

Comment: Is Orbeon 2017.2 compatible with eXist 4.3.0 or should I use eXist v1.4?

Comment: I am not aware of any incompatibility issue, so I'd recommend you go with the latest stable version of eXist (4.3.0 as of this writing), and report back if you find any problem with that version.